# Apache Camel - How to set global component options

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using Camel with Spring Boot. I want to set "connectionTimeToLive" option for http component at global scope so that every use of the component will have the option. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

After reading Camel test cases, I found out this solution using Custom Camel context configuration:

```
@Bean
CamelContextConfiguration contextConfiguration() {
    return new CamelContextConfiguration() {
        @Override
        public void beforeApplicationStart(CamelContext context) {
            HttpComponent http = context.getComponent("http4", HttpComponent.class);
            http.setConnectionTimeToLive(5000);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterApplicationStart(CamelContext camelContext) {

        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way Camel works, you will have to configure this value in a property placeholder.

Also you can define endpoints in camel, instead of defining them straight away in the routes. (Eg: `<endpoint id="bla" uri="foo" .. />`). This way you can refer them in multiple places.

Also if you want to use this endpoint for multiple hosts, then consider passing things like host name, etc as a header. Eg: Exchange.HTTP_PATH

I am not sure whether Camel has any other Global config approach.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options.

1. Add it to the camel registry and fetch it from there.
2. Add it as a Camel Exchange property.
3. Fetch it from a property file.